# Populate field in JSONforms and create dynamic form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsonschema

I am using [JSONforms](https://jsonforms.io/)

I have a simple scenario and don't quite know how this can be done with jsonforms:

I have two dropdowns, where the second dropdown is dependant on the first one.
For the sake of simplicity, the first one is "country", and the second one "state".
Now when someone selects a country (e.g. "USA") I would need

the "state" dropdown to be made editable (was readonly before)
populate the "state" dropdown with all states of the united states only.
Of course, once the "country" dropdown is set to another country, the dependant "state" field must be cleared!

How can I accomplish something like that - especially if the list of states must come from some rest api.. Any help would be highly appreciated. Please come up with solution using [JSONforms](https://jsonforms.io/)

Please note, I am using this [JSONforms](https://jsonforms.io/)

Not this [json-forms](https://github.com/brutusin/json-forms)